# How to include external pdf or rmd into quarto book?

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

I'm writing a Phd thesis as an Quarto book and have previously been using Rmd to create three papers which reside in their own Rmd projects. The projects use a lot of packages, such as flextable and officer. It works to render them both as .docx and .pdf. I want to add these papers at the end of the Quarto book as Appendix, but I can't figure out how to do it. I'm thinking it should be possible to either embed the pdf or render the projects again inside Quarto much like I can call external R scripts from within a Rmd project. Any help is appreciated!
BW
Martin

I tried to create a Paper1.qmd:

````
# Appendix A {.appendix}

```{r, include=FALSE}
sys.source("/home/martin/Dropbox/Martin/PhD/Dokumenter/Papers/Paper_1/Paper1_rmd/Paper1_7.Rmd", envir = knitr::knit_global())

```
````

It gives the following error:

```
processing file: Paper1.qmd
  |...................................                 |  67% [unnamed-chunk-1]
Quitting from lines 4-7 [unnamed-chunk-1] (Paper1.qmd)
Error in `parse()`:
! 8:12: unexpected symbol
7: author: 
8:   - Martin Randau
              ^
Backtrace:
 1. base::sys.source(...)
 2. base::parse(n = -1, file = file, srcfile = NULL, keep.source = FALSE)
                                                                                                            
Execution halted
```

**Edit**:
I also tried:

```
# Appendix A {.appendix}

{{< include _Paper1.Rmd >}}
```

and it renders somewhat but ends in an error:

```
Error running filter /usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:
.../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:3125: attempt to index a nil value (field 'integer index')
stack traceback:
    .../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:14819: in function 'tableCaptionsAndLabels'
    .../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:14782: in function <.../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:14751>
    [C]: in ?
    [C]: in method 'walk'
    .../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:171: in function 'run_emulated_filter'
    .../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:449: in local 'callback'
    .../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:454: in upvalue 'run_emulated_filter_chain'
    .../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:495: in function <.../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:476>
stack traceback:
    .../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:171: in function 'run_emulated_filter'
    .../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:449: in local 'callback'
    .../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:454: in upvalue 'run_emulated_filter_chain'
    .../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:495: in function <.../rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/share/filters/main.lua:476>
```

Comment: Is your final output pdf or html?

Comment: It shall be pdf. However, I have abandoned this problem to write the thesis in Overleaf (latex) instead. There's a function to directly attach a pdf document.